# PetaPoco and output parameters from stored procedures?

Tags: stored-procedures, petapoco, output-parameter

I'm trying to setup an output parameter using PetaPoco.  I found someone using this sample online:

```
var ctx = new CustomDBDatabase();
var total = new SqlParameter("Total", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
total.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

var results = ctx.Query<DBEntity>("exec GetDBEntities @StartIndex, @MaxIndex, @TotalCount = @Total out", 
  id, start, max, total);

int totalCount = (int)total.Value;
```

However, `total.value` returns null, even though when I run this statement directly against SQL Server, it returns me 3.  Is this setup correctly with PetaPoco?  Are output parameters supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is supported. But your current syntax is wrong anyways.

```
var ctx = new CustomDBDatabase();
var total = new SqlParameter("TotalCount", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
total.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

var results = ctx.Query<DBEntity>("exec GetDBEntities @StartIndex, @MaxIndex, @TotalCount OUTPUT", new { StartIndex = start, MaxIndex = max, TotalCount = total});

int totalCount = (int)total.Value;
```

Something like this should work though. Not quite sure of the sql syntax but this should get you on your way.

Comment: how would one write something similar for MySql?

Comment: use the mysql syntax for calling a SP.

Comment: What if you also need the return value?