# NPoco: Calling MySql procedure with OUT parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, orm, petapoco, npoco

In C#, using the NPoco (v3.4.3), I'm trying to invoke a MySQL procedure that returns both a result set and an OUT parameter...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(IN itemId INT, OUT returnCode INT)
BEGIN
    ...
    SET returnCode = -2;
    ...
    select * from MyTable where id = itemId;
END
```

I really have no clue where to start.  I have found some petapoco examples but they seem to be SQL Server specific (making use of SqlParameter).  There must be some noon-database specific way to accomplish this with NPoco that works with MySQL.

Comment: boy good luck with those tags on an intersect for this one :p Maybe you can make use of this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38706288) of mine. Returning a resultset is a trivial part which was not part of the exercise over there.

Comment: @Drew understood.  We have sort of worked around it for now (we returned two resultsets), but I'm sure there is a way, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried: `CALL MyProc(@1, @2); SELECT @2;`

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612167/petapoco-and-output-parameters-from-stored-procedures

Comment: Worked for me (npoco is petapoco fork)